# Homebrew on El Capitan - Not able to run "brew doctor"

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install Ruby and Rails, and I'm not able to get the installation to run. When I run RVM I get:

```
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool     pkg-config libyaml readline libksba openssl',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/Aman/.rvm/log/1448680507_ruby-2.2.1/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_libyaml_readline_libksba_openssl.log
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 1 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ case "$_system_version" in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

and When I run 'brew doctor' I get 
    'Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool'

Comment: do you have xcode installed?

Comment: I do. And I installed the command line tools when I installed homebrew.